# Proper Use Of Python 3.x AMFY Module

Tags: python-3.x, amf

How am I supposed to use the Amfy module? I try to use it like the JSON module (`amfy.loads` or `amfy.load`), but it just gives me errors:

```
C:\Users\Other>"C:\Users\Other\Desktop\Python3.5.2\test amf.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Other\Desktop\Python3.5.2\test amf.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(amfy.load(cn_rsp.text))
  File "C:\Users\Other\Desktop\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\amfy\__init__.py", line 9, in load
    return Loader().load(input, proto=proto)
  File "C:\Users\Other\Desktop\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\amfy\core.py", line 33, in load
    return self._read_item3(stream, context)
  File "C:\Users\Other\Desktop\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\amfy\core.py", line 52, in _read_item3
    marker = stream.read(1)[0]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

this is what I wrote:

```
import requests
import amfy
cn_rsp = requests.get("http://realm498.c10.castle.rykaiju.com/api/locales/en/get_serialized_new")
print(amfy.load(cn_rsp.text))
```

Answer (score 2):

After tinkering around and googling some stuff, I found a fix:
New code:

```
import amfy, requests, json

url = "http://realm416.c9.castle.rykaiju.com/api/locales/en/get_serialized_static"
req = requests.get(url)
if req.status_code == 200:
    ret = req.json() if "json" in req.headers["content-type"] else amfy.loads(req.content)
else:
    ret = {"failed": req.reason}

with open ("doa manifest.txt", 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as dump:
    json.dumps(ret, dump)
```

The Terminal throws a UnicodeEncodeError, but I was able to fix that by entering `chcp 65001` and then `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`

Answer (score 0):

The `load` method expects an input stream, you provide it a string. Just convert your string into a memory buffer which supports `read` method like this:

```
import io
print(amfy.load(io.BytesIO(cn_rsp.text.encode())))
```

unfortunately serialization fails when using this. Is there another url where it would work, a test URL maybe?

```
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\amfy\core.py", line 146, in _read_vli
    byte = stream.read(1)[0]
IndexError: index out of range
```

Comment: This creates another error: `File "C:\Users\Other\Desktop\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\amfy\core.py", line 141, in _read_item3
    raise NotImplementedError("Marker 0x{:02x}".format(marker))
ValueError: Unknown format code 'x' for object of type 'str'`

Comment: I have tested and I still cannot solve it. It's going further, but not solved.

Comment: I tried with [this](http://amf.wikispaces.com/file/view/Rook.amf/268219202/Rook.amf) but same error

Comment: are you sure the request is in the AMF format? I get: encoding text/html, there seem to be some text alongside some binary: sample `'\x01!no-current-event\x06\x1fEvent timed out\x11no-prize\x061The prize '
 'does not exist\x13no-tokens\x063Insufficient Dragon '
 'Teeth\x01+fortunas-arcade-prize\n'`

Comment: Supposedly it is AMF. I am simply trying to create a code for a game. I know another player has done this, but I have no contact with him.

Comment: looks like AMF, but still crashes. I successfully dumped/loaded some data with `amfy.dump` so I guess there is a serializing bug in the input data.